# access a set of seclectors with :before using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to javascript and jquery and... so I have question
How can I access my font-size in this set of selectors in my css using javascript code:

```
.bt-menu ul li a
{
display: block;
outline: none;
color: transparent;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 0px;
}
.bt-menu ul li a:before
{   
color: #fff;
font-size:35px;
opacity: 0.5;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

In my java script I tried this :

```
document.querySelector(".bt-menu ul li a:before").style.fontSize="12px";
```

but it didn't work , I tried

```
document.querySelector(".bt-menu ul li a").style.fontSize="12px";
```

it worked but it's not what I need, because with the :before it didn't work and I need to access the font size in 
bt-menu ul li a:before , can anyone guide me?

Comment: You cannot modify psudo-element CSS with JS